# Jackson with Spring Boot

Tags: json, jackson, spring-boot

Hi i used Jackson Faster for fetching the Data from Relational tables to avoid iteration while converting from **POJO to JSON.**

After i Posting same Entity Object  While it's giving an error.

**Error:**

```
ERROR 
. c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : 
Failed to evaluate deserialization for type 
[simple type, class com.nbfc.entity.CustmastState]:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
Multiple back-reference properties with name 'defaultReference'
```

Jackson: Multiple back-reference properties with name.

Please check this once..

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your entity contains a reference to another entity which has a reference back to it. Jackson doesn't like these circular references.

Hence the `@JsonBackReference` annotation. Annotate the entity reference with that annotation and Jackson will avoid such infinite loops.

Comment: Thanks Steve,yes it has Entity Reference I used @JsonBackReference so avoided Infinite loop. after i post the data using 'POST' method with the same entity . Then browser is returned an Unsupported media-type here it's unable to De-serialize  Object  ,The above issue is given When i post data to the Server.

Comment: Pretty sure you're not going to be able to post an entity and all its linked entities to your services as a single object unless you do the parsing yourself. You might be better creating a separate resource class just for the API interface. Alternatively, depending on how you are doing things, it might be feasible to use the `@XmlTransient` / `@JsonIgnore` annotations so that it doesn't even try marshalling linked entities.